# Evento Jquery teclado não responde

Tags: jquery, eventos

Fiz esse script para movimentar uma div ao pressionar as setas do teclado. A tecla direita e baixo estão funcionando perfeitamente, porem, as cima e esquerda não estão, o codigo ta igual dos outros.

Segue o codigo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>        



    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).keydown(function(x){
        if(x.which == 39 || x.keyCode == 39){               
             $('div').animate({left: '1180px'});                 
        }           
      }).keyup(function(){
        $('div').animate().stop();
      });
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).keydown(function(x){
        if(x.which == 40 || x.keyCode == 40){               
             $('div').animate({top: '1180px'});              
        }           
      }).keyup(function(){
        $('div').stop();
      });
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).keydown(function(x){
        if(x.which == 37 || x.keyCode == 37){               
             $('div').animate({right: '1180px'});                
        }           
      }).keyup(function(){
        $('div').stop();
      });
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(document).keydown(function(x){
        if(x.which == 38 || x.keyCode == 38){               
             $('div').animate({ '1180px'});              
        }           
      }).keyup(function(){
        $('div').stop();
      });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da maneira que você fez ficou adicionado múltiplos eventos para quando aperta uma tecla, o keyup foi adicionado 4 vezes por exemplo, talvez ele esteja conflitando com os outros keyDowns, realmente não é necessário fazer um evento para cada, o melhor é tudo dentro de um único evento e usar os ifs ou um switch para isto

Note também que o não tem propriedade definida em `if(x.which == 38 || x.keyCode == 38)`, você adicionou apenas o 1180px:

```
$('div').animate({ '1180px'});
```

Outra coisa, você adicionou .animate() sem necessidade:

```
  $(document).keydown(function(x){
    if(x.which == 39 || x.keyCode == 39){               
         $('div').animate({left: '1180px'});                 
    }           
  }).keyup(function(){
    $('div').animate().stop(); ///<--- aqui
  });
```

No exemplo a seguir troquei `$('div')` por `.personagem` para não afetar outros divs e de preferencia troque o `right` e `bottom` por left e top com numeros nagativos, assim o jQuery vai subtrair da propriedades já definidas e o CSS funciona bem com numeros negativos:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).keydown(function(x){
    var keycode = x.which || x.keyCode; //Pega o código da tecla

    switch (keycode) {
        case 39:
            $('.personagem').animate({left: '1180px'});
        break;
        case 40:
            $('.personagem').animate({top: '1180px'});
        break;
        case 37:
            $('.personagem').animate({left: '-1180px'});
        break;
        case 38:
            $('.personagem').animate({top: '-1180px'});
        break;
    }           
  }).keyup(function(){
       $('.personagem').stop();
  });
});
```

```css
.personagem {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="personagem"></div>
```

Uma outra coisa que pode ser interessante fazer é adicionar .stop para acaso outro evento inicie, mesmo que o keyup não seja disparado, por exemplo:

```
switch (keycode) {
    case 39:
        $('.personagem').stop().animate({left: '1180px'});
    break;
    case 40:
        $('.personagem').stop().animate({top: '1180px'});
    break;
    case 37:
        $('.personagem').stop().animate({left: '-1180px'});
    break;
    case 38:
        $('.personagem').stop().animate({top: '-1180px'});
    break;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, funcionou perfeitamente. Excelentes dicas.

Comment: @blackbird312 por favor marque a resposta como correta se lhe resolveu o problema ;)